# flutter : insert data to list and keep old data

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

i have a List :-

```
List salesr;
```

after fetch data from API i add this result to this List :-

```
salesr = redata["rows"];
print(salesr);
```

output :-

```
[{customer_name: null, outgoing_id: 33, outgoing_code: 000000042, outgoing_totalAll: 23.0000, outgoing_date: 2021-01-22, customer_id: null}]
```

now when i print this list it working good ..
my qustion is how to add another data to this list ? i want to keep old data just insert .

i tried to add by this way :

```
salesr.add(redata["rows"]);
```

but not working

Comment: what is `Session()` ?

Comment: class to post API .. and return

Comment: Can you add an error to the question?

Comment: the problem with this line :  salesr = redata["rows"];  .. when i call function it remove all data in list and put new data .. i want to add the new data plus old data

Comment: i update my qustion , sorry for that , my english is not good

Comment: How did you know that is `salesr.add(redata["rows"]);` don't works?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use addAll to add all new data into your list

```
salesr.addAll(redata["rows"]);
```